# How to insert null in table with python-sqlite3?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In sqlite console,we can insert null simple.

```
create table data(code TEXT,date  DATETIME)
insert into data values("x1","20010101");
insert into data values("x2",null);
```

how to insert null with python-sqlite3?

```
import sqlite3 
db = r'F:\test.sqlite'
con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('create table data(code TEXT,date  DATETIME)')
record1=('x1','2001-01-01')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record1)
record2=('x2','NULL')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record2)
record3=('x2','null')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record3)
record4=('x4',null)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record4)
record5=('x5',NULL)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record5)
con.commit()
```

`cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record2)`insert a string of `NULL` into table ,not null.
`cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record3)`insert a string of `null` into table ,not null.

Neither of cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record4) OR cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record5)    can insert null into the table data.

How can i insert null into table with python-sqlite3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#introduction) says:

> The following Python types can thus be sent to SQLite without any problem:
>
> ```
> Python type   SQLite type
> None          NULL
> ...
> ```

Comment: record=('x',None)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?);',record)